# MyISAM - turn off query_cache?

Tags: mysql, database

I have been looking at a lot of my.cnf configs and wanted to know for a MyISAM db, is it better to have a small query_cache or turn off query_cache and just have a big key_buffer_size? How should these two relate?

Here is an auto generated my.cnf file based on my server configuration (8GB / Dedicated Virtual)

```
 [mysqld]
 # MyISAM #
 key_buffer_size                = 2G

 # SAFETY #
 max_allowed_packet             = 16M
 max_connect_errors             = 1000000

 # CACHES AND LIMITS #
 tmp_table_size                 = 32M
 max_heap_table_size            = 32M
 query_cache_type               = 0
 query_cache_size               = 0
 max_connections                = 500
 thread_cache_size              = 50
 open_files_limit               = 65535
 table_definition_cache         = 1024
 table_open_cache               = 2048
```

And another from a human:

```
 [mysqld]

 # MyISAM #
 key_buffer_size                = 4G

 # SAFETY #
 max_allowed_packet             = 1M

 # CACHES AND LIMITS #
 tmp_table_size                 = 64M
 max_heap_table_size            = 64M
 query_cache_type               = 1
 query_cache_size               = 128M
 max_connections                = 500
 thread_cache_size              = 256
 table_open_cache               = 1024
```